# MSBI vs Power BI and their usage

Tags: powerbi, msbi

This question is generic and may have multiple answers. I've been in Power BI world for a few years and curious to know the technical differences between **MSBI** & **Power BI**. Both belong to Microsoft products and why they have a couple of Business Intelligence in their branch.

Comment: from my short understanding, MSBI is more focused towards ETL and providing services for SQL servers. PowerBI is more point and click data viz platform where you can model your data. 

My understanding is that PowerBI was developed to compete with tableau, looker, sisense, etc. Seeing how MSFT is going after slack with Microsoft Teams, you can kind of see what will happen for their BI portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

**Power BI Consists of:**

1. Power BI Desktop
2. Power BI Service
3. Report Server

**MSBI Consists of:**

1. SSRS - SQL Server Reporting Service
2. SSIS - SQL Server Integration Service
3. SSAS - SQL Server Analytic Service

So as it shows, the only common part in Power BI and MSBI is the reporting services. However, Data manipulation and modeling is far more superior in Power BI compared to in SSRS. Also Power BI uses an SSAS model behind the picture for whatever modeling capacities it provides.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft Business Inteligence` (**MSBI**) include many things like ,`SQL Server` ,`SQl Server Integration service`(`SSIS`), `SSRS`, and `SSAS` as well.
So role and responsibilities are totally different of `MSBI` and `Power BI`.
**MSBI** developer expertise in (`Export Transport and Load`) **ETL** development ,`Data warehousing` and `reporting` as well but can't aspect same with `Power BI developer`.